# Should I call this distribution a Beta distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function, gamma-distribution

Let $m, n >0$ fixed. I have this random variable $X$ whose pdf $f(x)$ is defined as:

$f(x)=\frac{\frac{x^{m - 1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}}{B(m,n)}, x \in [1, \infty), f(x)= 0 $ elsewhere.

N.B. **Yes it is really $[1, \infty),$ not $[0, \infty).$**

We can see that $f(x) \ge 0, \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=1,$ so clearly $f(x)$ is a PDF. But I'm wondering whether I should call $X$ to follow the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $m,n$, as normally Beta distribution has support on $[0,1]$ only, not on $[1, \infty)$. If the answer is yes, great! If we can't call $X$ to follow a Beta distribution, should we say $X$ follow a transformed beta distribution? Is there any name for $X?$ Clearly, $X=\frac{B}{1-B}, B \sim B(m,n).$ But this transformation is bijective, so should we also call $X$ to be a Beta random variable?

Thank you!

**ADDENDUM:** To deter any confusion that may arise after reading the answer(s), let me state that I made a bad mistake in defining $f(x)$ earlier: I defined it as:

$f(x)=\frac{\frac{x^{m/2 - 1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}}{B(m,n)}, x \in [1, \infty), f(x)= 0 $ elsewhere.

which was *not* the intended definition.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a [beta prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution?wprov=sfla1) distribution although the support doesn't match.

Comment: If $X=B/(1-B)$ then the support is $[0,\infty)$ (not $[1,\infty)$) and this is indeed a beta prime distribution.

Comment: _Clearly_ $X = B/(1-B), B ~ B(m, n)?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thanks, I just looked up the Beta prime distribution, and yes, it indeed seems like one, but the supports aren't matching. I'll check my calculations and see...

Is there any distribution related to the Beta or Beta prime distributions whose support is indeed $[1, \infty)?$

Comment: @LearningMath You distribution IS a beta prime and the support must be $[0,\infty)$. If $X=B/(1-B)$ then what is the value of $X$ when $B=0$?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thanks, yes I agree that it is a Beta prime distribution, although I still need to check my calculation to make sure that the density calculation was fully correct. What I'm sure of is that at the end it'll be a distribution (Beta prime or not, depending on the correctness of my calculation) whose support is indeed $[1,\infty),$ not $[0,\infty).$ This is indeed a small part of a research problem where I could use your insight and give you due credit. So if you're interested in a collaboration, I could contact you privately? It is perfectly okay if not!

Comment: @AaronHendrickson  Thanks, you'll hear from me in a few days.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Just sent the email, after a long delay!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you seem to think that $f$ integrates to $1$.  To rephrase your claimed density, it says

$$f(x \mid m,n) = \frac{\Gamma(m+n)}{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)} x^{m/2 - 1} (1+x)^{-(m+n)}. \tag{1}$$  We will deal with the question of the support later.  Now consider the case $m = 2$:  We get

$$f(x \mid 2, n) = \frac{\Gamma(2+n)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(n)} x^0 (1+x)^{-(2+n)} = \frac{n(n+1)}{x^{n+2}}. \tag{2}$$  Its antiderivative is

$$\int f(x \mid 2,n) \, dx = \frac{n}{(x+1)^{n+1}} + C. \tag{3}$$  So its integral on $[0, \infty)$ is $n$, and on $[1,\infty)$, it is $n/2^{n+1}$, neither of which is $1$ except when $n = 1$ in the first case and certainly not for any general $n$.  Therefore, your claim that $f$ integrates to $1$ is false.

If the support is on $[0,\infty)$, then the correct constant of proportionality that makes $f$ a density is not $1/B(m,n)$ but instead $$\frac{\Gamma(m+n)}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m}{2}+n)} = \frac{1}{B(\frac{m}{2}, \frac{m}{2} + n)}.$$  You may verify this yourself with a suitable choice of $m, n$.

If the support is on $[1,\infty)$, then the constant includes a hypergeometric factor.

As for your claim that $X = B/(1-B)$ where $B$ is beta with general parameters $m, n$, the actual PDF of the transformed variable is

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{B(m,n)} x^{m-1} (1+x)^{-(m+n)} \mathbb 1 (x > 0). \tag{4}$$  That is to say, the support of such a variable is on $(0,\infty)$, which should be obvious from the transformation itself, since $$\lim_{B \to 0^+} \frac{B}{1-B} = 0$$ and in particular, $B = 1/3$ implies $X = (1/3)/(1-1/3) = 1/2 < 1$.

Returning to your original question about the name of such a distribution, if the support is on $(0,\infty)$, then $X = B/(1-B)$ as illustrated in $(4)$ is called Beta prime, or inverted beta, although I avoid the latter terminology to avoid confusion with "inverse beta", which is presumably $Y = 1/B$, with density

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{B(m,n)} y^{-(m+n)} (y-1)^{n-1} \mathbb 1 (y > 1). \tag{5}$$

If we wish to retain the shape of $(4)$ but restrict the support to $[1,\infty)$, then this would be a **left-truncated** Beta prime distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just figured that I made a big typo in the definition of $f(x)$, it should be : $f(x)=\frac{\frac{x^{m - 1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}}{B(m,n)}, x \in [1, \infty), f(x)= 0 $ elsewhere. I just corrected it. In this case, the integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty}f = \int_{0}^{\infty}=1, $ since $f \equiv 0$ on $[0,1,]$ correct?